# Apricity database not found

Tags: database, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I recently installed apricity-os and when trying to use pacman, I was prompted with an error message saying that I didn't have the apricity-core database .I wished to know of one of you could help me find it .

Comment: @EliasMP you can shorthand those links with `[MCVE]` , `[help]` and `[ask]` as so: [MCVE],  [help], and  [ask] . That'll save you link copying in the future.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: [help], then read: [MCVE] and: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Apricity OS support is ended, as reported here https://apricity-os.github.io/.